# In classical electrodynamics, what are the equations of motion for a pair of point charges?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, classical-electrodynamics

I know the equations for a (point) charge in a background electromagnetic field, and for the electromagnetic field due to a fixed current. What are the general equations, for the evolution of an initial field and charge distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Together the Lorentz force law and Maxwell’s equations fully specify the dynamics of a system of charged particles. The accelerating charges source an electromagnetic field via Maxwell’s equations, which in turn acts on the charged particles via the Lorentz force law.